# Knockoutjs Function Expected Exception on updating model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

After much research and trail and error, I haven't come up with a solution yet.  Please help!  The SearchCustomer method in the code has comments on the scenarios that work and don't work.

**Situation**

I use knockoutjs with the mapping plugin.  I take a view model which contains a Workorder from the server and it contains some properties about it along with a Customer model underneath it and a Contact model underneath Customer.

On the workorder screen the user can search for a customer which pops up a modal search window.  They select that customer and the customer's id and customer model comes back to the workorder.  I update the workorder's customerID no problem, but when I try to update the customer data (including contact) I get the Function Expected error.

**Code**

```
function WorkorderViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};
    mapping = {
        'Workorder': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new Workorder(options.data, self);
            }
        }
    }

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);

    self.ViewCustomer = function () {
        self.Workorder.Customer.View();
    }

    self.SearchCustomer = function () {
        self.Workorder.Customer.Search(function (customerID, customer) {
            self.Workorder.CustomerID(customerID); //Works
            self.Workorder.Customer(customer) //Function Expected, I feel this should work! Please help!
            self.Workorder.Customer = new Customer(customer, self.Workorder); //No Error doesn't update screen
            self.Workorder.Customer.Contact.FirstName(customer.Contact.FirstName); //Works, updates screen, but I don't want to do this for every property.
            self.Workorder.SaveAll(); //Works, reload page and customer data is correct.  Not looking to reload webpage everytime though.
        })
    }
}

function Workorder(data, parent) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};
    mapping = {
        'Customer': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new Customer(options.data, self);
            }
        }
    }

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
}

function Customer(data, parent) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};
    mapping = {
        'Contact': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new Contact(options.data, self);
            }
        }
    }

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
}

function Contact(data, parent) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};
    mapping = {};

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);

    self.AddedOn = ko.observable(moment(data.AddedOn).year() == 1 ? '' : moment(data.AddedOn).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));

    self.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
        var fullName = '';

        if (self.FirstName() != null && self.FirstName() != '') {
            fullName = self.FirstName();
        }

        if (self.MiddleName() != null && self.MiddleName() != '') {
            fullName += ' ' + self.MiddleName();
        }

        if (self.LastName() != null && self.LastName() != '') {
            fullName += ' ' + self.LastName();
        }

        return fullName;
    })
}
```

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you create a reproduction somewhere (jsfiddle)

Comment: I see your issue and I think you may want to create a "UpdateCustomer" method on your Workorder object, that takes a Customer "raw-data" or "vm-like" shaped object and uses either DaveB's approach (but encapsulated) or the mapping plugin to update its internal Customer.

Comment: Thanks, tried an approach that I think you were saying but essentially I agree with the concept of UpdateCustomer which is my goal.  I have updated the website to show this and alert the json of the customer object being returned.  I'm going to keep trying ideas but thanks so far for looking into it.

Comment: Ok, the Customer object is not an observable.  Clearly being used in the mapping create feature of knockout, but since my customer isn't a list/array coming from my .net model only the properties are becoming observable.  If I pass an array in and alert it instead of [object Object] I get the lovely knockout observable text.  Shouldn't the mapping utility make the customer an observable not just it's properties?  I'm getting closer but not to the answer I want to see...

Comment: Would it make sense to use `ko.mapping` to change the value? Something like  `ko.mapping.fromJS(customer, self.Workorder.Customer)`

Comment: It definitely would! I swear I tried that but realized I was doing self.Workorder.Customer = ko.mapping.fromJS(customer).  Thanks, that is awesome!  Roy your suggestion worked!  Glad it was something minor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `self.Workorder.Customer` is originally populated using `ko.mapping`, when you want to repopulate it, you should use `ko.mapping` again, like:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(customer, self.Workorder.Customer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
self.Workorder.Customer(customer);
```

to:

```
self.Workorder.Customer = customer;
```

My guess is that the Customer property of the Workorder is not an observable.

Comment: Sorry I have tried that also with no luck, I updated my link with this attempt as well to show it doesn't work.  Thanks for the suggestion though!